# The time at which a car starts to skid on a rotating platform

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

I am trying to solve the following problem from the book "An Introduction To Mechanics" by Daniel Kleppner and Robert Kolenkow.

> $1.18$ $ $ Car on rotating platform
> A car is driven on a large revolving platform which rotates with
> constant angular speed $\omega$. At $t=0$ a driver leaves the origin and
> follows a line painted radially outward on the platform with constant
> speed $v_0$. The total weight of the car is $W$, and the coefficient
> of friction between the car and stage is $\mu$.
> $ $
> (a) Find the acceleration of the  car as a function of time using
> polar coordinates. Draw a clear vector diagram showing the components
> of acceleration at some time $t>0$.
> (b) Find the time at which the car just starts to skid.

I was able to solve (a) using the equation of acceleration in polar coordinates
$$\boldsymbol{a}=(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2)\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}+(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$$

I got
$$\boldsymbol{a}=-v_0t\omega^2\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}+2v_0\omega\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$$

But I don't understand the solution for (b).

The solution of (b) from the solutions manual:

> The car starts to skid when
> $$Ma\geq f_{max}=\mu W=\mu Mg$$
> $$a=\sqrt{a_r^2+a_\theta^2}=\sqrt{v_0^2t^2\omega^4+4v_0^2\omega^2}\geq \mu g$$
> Skidding just starts at $t_0$, where
> $$(\mu g)^2=v_0^2\omega^4t_0^2+4v_0^2\omega^2$$
> $$t_0=\frac{1}{v_0\omega^2}\sqrt{(\mu g)^2-4v_0^2\omega^2}$$

Why the car starts to skid when $Ma\geq f_{max}$ ?
For $Ma>f_{max}$ there must be a force other than friction acting on the car. but the only force I found that is acting on the car is friction (gravity and normal cancel each other) so how could $Ma>f_{max}$
$ $
Can someone please help me understand the solution?
$ $
(I did not include the vector diagrams in this solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Ma$ expresses a force. Friction is: $f = μN = μmg$ right? The car accelerates with a certain acceleration which results to a certain force. Once the magnitude of that force ($Ma$) becomes equal with the maximum magnitude of friction ($μmg$), the car skids. I hope this helped.

Comment: You wrote, "Once the magnitude of that force (Ma) becomes..." But what causes "that" force. is it the car?

Comment: By "is it the car", I assume you mean the engine. No, as the problem states, the car has a constant speed. The idea here is that you are on a revolving plane. Therefore, your reference system is not inertial. Newton's law needs a "correction term" in the case of non-inertial systems. It is: $\vec{a}_{\Sigma} = \Sigma \vec{F} - \vec{a}_o - 2\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r} - \omega^2 r - \dot{\vec{\omega}} \times r$.

Comment: Is this force that causes the acceleration of the car called a "fictitious force" or am I confusing two different things? I am not quite familiar with non-inertial systems, so forgive me for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes this is called a fictitious force. The term $2\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}$ is called Coriolis force, $\dot{\vec{\omega}}\times\vec{r}$ is called Euler force.